# What happens to the exponential generating function if the sequence is "stretched"?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Consider a real-valued sequence $(a_0,a_1,a_2,....)$ and the "$n$-stretch"-transformation, which inserts $n$ zeros between each element, for example $n=2$ would represent the transformation

$$(a_0,a_1,a_2,...)\mapsto(a_0,0,0,a_1,0,0,a_2,0,0,...).$$

Now, considering the sequence's generating function
$$G(x)=a_0+a_1 x+a_2 x^2+...,$$ 
obviously, the $n$-stretch is represented by 
$$G(x)\mapsto G(x^{n+1}).$$

Now I wonder if for the *exponential* generating function

$$E(x)=a_0 + a_1\frac{x^1}{1!} + a_2\frac{x^2}{2!}+...,$$

there exists also such a simple representation

$$E(x)\mapsto?$$

Comment: It seems unlikely to me. Note that the $2$-stretch sends $\frac{1}{1-x}$ to [a complicated expression involving the Gaussian error function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+x%5E%282n%29+%28n%21%29%2F%282n%29%21+for+n+from+0+to+infinity). And [WolframAlpha can't even do](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+x%5E%283n%29+%28n%21%29%2F%283n%29%21+for+n+from+0+to+infinity) its $3$-stretch.

Comment: @Micah Excuse me if this is trivial, as I'm just a hobbyist in this field, but would the answer for $\frac{1}{1-x}$ straighforwardly lead to the answer for general $E(x)$?

Comment: The $N=n-1$ translation of $G(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_kx^k}{k!}$ becomes $\hat{G}_{n-1}(x) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{a_kx^{nk}}{(nk)!}$. The mixing of $n$ with $k$ in $(nk)!$ (which is not there in the standard generating function) makes it very unlikely there exist a simple relation. btw Micah's example above is a $n=1$ stretch of $a_k=k!$.

Comment: @flonk: The answer for $\frac{1}{1-x}$ doesn't lead to the answer for general $E(x)$ (to the best of my knowledge). However, if there was a nice relationship in general, it would certainly be true of $\frac{1}{1-x}$ in particular. My claim is that the particular functions you get don't look like they could possibly come from a nice general relationship.

Comment: You may want to read about [generalized hypergeometric functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_hypergeometric_function). If $E(z)$ is already such a function, say $E(z)={}_pF_q(a_1,\dots,a_p;b_1,\dots,b_q;z)$, then so are all its stretched versions, more or less. If you stretch by $k$, then assuming I've done my algebra right you get the function $E_k(z)={}_pF_{q+k}(a_1,\dots,a_p;b_1,\dots,b_q,\frac{1}{k+1},\frac{2}{k+1},\dots ,\frac{k}{k+1};\left(\frac{z}{k+1}\right)^{k+1})$.   This probably doesn't help in general, though...